# Keeping minimum when converting from shapefile to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, shapefile, vector

I have a shapefile that I am trying to convert to raster. The shapefile has overlapping polygons. I would like to keep the minumum value of these overlapping polygons when converting to raster.

[image]

Right now, when I use the Feature to Raster dataset within the 'To Raster' toolbox, it keeps the maximum of the overlapping polygons. Can I change this so it keeps the minimum?
Or will I have to clean up my shapefile to get rid of the overlapping areas.

Answer (score 1):

Convert each polygon to [raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm). I would [iterate through the features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm) in a model to achieve this.
Combine the rasters using [cell statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) > minimum. Be sure to use union of inputs as the processing extent.

You have a raster of the lowest values for each pixel as output.